# cant edit layout.Css file in joomla

Tags: css, joomla2.5

i have joomla 2,5 and beez_20 template im using ftp to change css.

i tried to change some css codes such styling ,colors , fonts ,....

however when i change and upload it it shows changed . but after a while the changes they gone and the original code back . its like that i didnt change !!

my website looks weird if i dont changes . example uppercase i want change etc ...

is there something which generate this file ? is it from .acesss ? please let me know how i can change . tried from backend and same thing . everything rolls back after a while . i dont know how much time that its rollsback but when i check later i found the css unchanged :( !!

my file is `/templates/beez_20/css/layout.css`

help please !

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any caching enabled? Sounds kind of like some issue with caching to me.

Also which file are you editing? The one in `/templates/beez_20/css/layout.css` would be the right one.

Comment: its the same file i have . and caching is disabled .

Comment: Sounds strange then. Joomla certainly doesn't do this, except if you update Joomla of course. Then it may overwrite your changes.
You can create a copy of the template to avoid this.

Comment: i have edited the css file more then 5 times and looks good , but the day after  rolls back again , like i didnt change ,

Comment: Contact your hoster and ask him if there is some cronjob running which does some funny things. Joomla certainly doesn't do that itself. There must be some backup/restore functions or some caching issue of some sort.